# Minimal pyhf example failing with 'Inequality constraints incompatible'

Tags: python, scipy, pyhf

I am trying to build a pretty minimal pyhf example: two gaussians, one signal and one background, but I can't get it to work. My python code is:

```
import pyhf.readxml
import os
from ROOT import TH1F, TFile, TF1

mygaus = TF1("mygaus","TMath::Gaus(x,100,.5)",95, 115)
mygaus2 = TF1("mygaus2","TMath::Gaus(x,110,.2)",95, 115)
mygaus_data = TF1("mygaus_data","TMath::Gaus(x,110,.2)+TMath::Gaus(x,100,.5)",95, 115)

bkg_nominal = TH1F('bkg_nominal', '', 80, 95, 115)
bkg_nominal.FillRandom("mygaus", 10000)

sig_nominal = TH1F('sig_nominal', '', 80, 95, 115)
sig_nominal.FillRandom("mygaus2", 5000)

data_nominal = TH1F('data_nominal', '', 80, 95, 115)
data_nominal.FillRandom("mygaus_data", 10000)

meas = TFile('meas.root', 'RECREATE')
bkg_nominal.Write()
sig_nominal.Write()
data_nominal.Write()
meas.Close()

spec = pyhf.readxml.parse('meas.xml', os.getcwd())
workspace = pyhf.Workspace(spec)

pdf = workspace.model(measurement_name='meas')
data = workspace.data(pdf)
workspace.get_measurement(measurement_name='meas')
best_fit = pyhf.infer.mle.fit(data, pdf)
```

The XML file, which I basically copied from the example in the documentation, are written like this

meas.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE Combination  SYSTEM 'HistFactorySchema.dtd'>

<Combination OutputFilePrefix="workspace" >


  <Input>./meas_channel1.xml</Input>

  <Measurement Name="meas" Lumi='1' LumiRelErr='0.1' ExportOnly="False"  >
    <POI>signorm</POI>
  </Measurement>

</Combination>
```

meas_channel1.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE Channel  SYSTEM 'HistFactorySchema.dtd'>

  <Channel Name="channel1" InputFile="" >

    <Data HistoName="data_nominal" InputFile="meas.root" />

    <StatErrorConfig RelErrorThreshold="0.05" ConstraintType="Gaussian" />

    <Sample Name="bkg"  HistoName="bkg_nominal"  InputFile="meas.root"  NormalizeByTheory="True" >
      <NormFactor Name="bkgnorm"  Val="1"  High="3"  Low="0"  Const="False"   />
    </Sample>

    <Sample Name="sig"   HistoName="sig_nominal"  InputFile="meas.root"  NormalizeByTheory="True" >
      <NormFactor Name="signorm"  Val="1"  High="3"  Low="0"  Const="False"   />
    </Sample>

  </Channel>
```

It looks all pretty simple and I am able to plot the histograms. However, when I get this error message:

```
ERROR:pyhf.optimize.opt_scipy:     fun: nan
     jac: array([nan, nan, nan])
 message: 'Inequality constraints incompatible'
    nfev: 5
     nit: 1
    njev: 1
  status: 4
 success: False
       x: array([1., 1., 1.])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-54e7c2f0a645> in <module>
      2 data = workspace.data(pdf)
      3 workspace.get_measurement(measurement_name='meas')
----> 4 best_fit = pyhf.infer.mle.fit(data, pdf)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyhf/infer/mle.py in fit(data, pdf, init_pars, par_bounds, **kwargs)
     34     init_pars = init_pars or pdf.config.suggested_init()
     35     par_bounds = par_bounds or pdf.config.suggested_bounds()
---> 36     return opt.minimize(twice_nll, data, pdf, init_pars, par_bounds, **kwargs)
     37 
     38 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyhf/optimize/opt_scipy.py in minimize(self, objective, data, pdf, init_pars, par_bounds, fixed_vals, return_fitted_val)
     45         )
     46         try:
---> 47             assert result.success
     48         except AssertionError:
     49             log.error(result)

AssertionError:
```

which is weird because I don't have any inequality constraint. I think I am doing something dumb, could you please help? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the good question @robsol90.

If we visually inspect the contents of the model (open the ROOT file and look at the historgrams in `TBrowser`) or just print out the contents (after converting the XML+ROOT to JSON)

```py
>>> import json
>>> with open("meas.json") as spec_file:
...     spec = json.load(spec_file)
...
>>> print(json.dumps(spec, indent=2, sort_keys=True))
```

We see that there are *many* bins with zeros in the model. This is a problem as HistFactory is Poisson based, and as the Poisson p.m.f. is defined strictly for rate parameters greater than 0 these true 0 bins will cause errors (and they do).
However, if we simply parse the spec and add a *very* small offset (`epsilon`) then the fit is able to proceed without any problem.
So this problem actually ends up being very similar to this question ([Fit convergence failure in pyhf for small signal model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60089405/fit-convergence-failure-in-pyhf-for-small-signal-model)) without it being immediately apparent.

We understand that the toy model you setup was supposed to be minimal and easy, but as in reality you will almost never encounter such a sparse analysis region this toy problem becomes difficult. *We will take efforts in the future though to automatically mask bins that are true zeros in the model to avoid this issue for the users altogether.*

I'll also give below some code that fixes the problem you have above as well as some additional example code.

---

First, to be very clear, let's establish our environment

### Environment

```
$ "$(which python3)" --version
Python 3.7.5
$ python3 -m venv "${HOME}/.venvs/question"
$ . "${HOME}/.venvs/question/bin/activate"
(question) $ cat requirements.txt
pyhf[xmlio]~=0.4.0
black
(question) $ python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
(question) $ root-config --version
6.18/04
```

### Code

Let's also break things apart into multiple steps of the code. First let's look at the XML to ROOT code snippet, which I've modified so that there is a more reasonable sampling of the model displayed in the observed data (**but did not need to** as your original code would work here too).

```py
# XML_to_ROOT.py
from ROOT import TH1F, TFile, TF1


def main():
    left_bound = 95
    right_bound = 115
    n_bins = 80

    # Model makeup
    frac_bkg = 0.95
    frac_sig = round(1.0 - frac_bkg, 2)

    bkg_model = TF1("bkg_model", "TMath::Gaus(x,100,0.5,true)", left_bound, right_bound)
    sig_model = TF1("sig_model", "TMath::Gaus(x,105,0.2,true)", left_bound, right_bound)
    obs_model = TF1(
        "obs_model",
        f"({frac_bkg}*bkg_model)+({frac_sig}*sig_model)",
        left_bound,
        right_bound,
    )

    # Samples from model
    n_sample = 10000
    n_bkg = int(frac_bkg * n_sample)
    n_sig = int(frac_sig * n_sample)

    bkg_nominal = TH1F("bkg_nominal", "", n_bins, left_bound, right_bound)
    bkg_nominal.FillRandom("bkg_model", n_bkg)

    sig_nominal = TH1F("sig_nominal", "", n_bins, left_bound, right_bound)
    sig_nominal.FillRandom("sig_model", n_sig)

    data_nominal = TH1F("data_nominal", "", n_bins, left_bound, right_bound)
    data_nominal.FillRandom("obs_model", n_sample)

    meas = TFile("meas.root", "RECREATE")
    bkg_nominal.Write()
    sig_nominal.Write()
    data_nominal.Write()
    meas.Close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Now to make things easier later let's generate our XML and ROOT file and then convert them into a JSON spec

```
(question) $ python XML_to_ROOT.py
(question) $ pyhf xml2json --output-file meas.json meas.xml
```

Now, finally, let's adapt the code in your question to make sure that no bins in the model contain true `0`s by padding all bins with an offset of `1e-20` (just to demonstrate that the only important thing is that they are non-zero)

```py
# answer.py
import os
import json
import pyhf.readxml
import numpy as np


def main():
    with open("meas.json") as spec_file:
        spec = json.load(spec_file)

    # Pad true zeros to avoid error with evaluating Poisson(x|0)
    epsilon = 1e-20
    bkg = np.asarray(spec["channels"][0]["samples"][0]["data"]) + epsilon
    sig = np.asarray(spec["channels"][0]["samples"][1]["data"]) + epsilon
    spec["channels"][0]["samples"][0]["data"] = bkg.tolist()
    spec["channels"][0]["samples"][1]["data"] = sig.tolist()

    workspace = pyhf.Workspace(spec)

    model = workspace.model(measurement_name="meas")
    data = workspace.data(model)

    best_fit_pars = pyhf.infer.mle.fit(data, model)
    print(f"initialization parameters: {model.config.suggested_init()}")
    print(
        f"best fit parameters:\
        \n * signal strength: {best_fit_pars[0]}\
        \n * nuisance parameters: {best_fit_pars[1:]}"
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Now running we get

```
(question) $ python answer.py 
initialization parameters: [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
best fit parameters:        
 * signal strength: 1.000000316044688        
 * nuisance parameters: [0.99884051 1.02202245]
```

---

As an extra demonstration that this is *really* just due to true zeros, consider the following 2 bin example that is engineered to fail with your error.

```py
# fail.py
import os
import json
import pyhf.readxml
import numpy as np


def main():
    with open("meas.json") as spec_file:
        spec = json.load(spec_file)

    # Fails
    bkg = np.asarray([0, 0])
    sig = np.asarray([0, 1])
    obs = np.asarray([1, 1])
    # # Fails
    # bkg = np.asarray([1, 0])
    # sig = np.asarray([0, 0])
    # obs = np.asarray([1, 1])
    # # Fails
    # bkg = np.asarray([0, 0])
    # sig = np.asarray([0, 0])
    # obs = np.asarray([1, 1])
    # # Pass
    # bkg = np.asarray([1e-9, 0])
    # sig = np.asarray([0, 1e-9])
    # obs = np.asarray([1, 1])
    spec["channels"][0]["samples"][0]["data"] = bkg.tolist()
    spec["channels"][0]["samples"][1]["data"] = sig.tolist()
    spec["observations"][0]["data"] = obs.tolist()

    workspace = pyhf.Workspace(spec)

    model = workspace.model(measurement_name="meas")
    data = workspace.data(model)

    best_fit_pars = pyhf.infer.mle.fit(data, model)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Could you simplify things by allowing Poisson rate parameter of 0. The limit is perfectly well-behaved. It’s implemented that way in R https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Poisson.html

Comment: Maybe we should discuss this over on https://github.com/scikit-hep/pyhf/issues/293, which has been open for some time on this point. This seems philosophically wrong though, as the rate parameter is strictly > 0.

Comment: sure, pyhf is very interesting, I’ll write something at the GitHub issue later

Answer (score 0):

Hi @robsol90 can you dump the full JSON spec `pdf.spec` and share it here?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. The JSON file is a bit large, so you can find it here: https://gist.github.com/soleti/0185cb6e7e4732d4156abe802bb52213