# Upper limit for n_background == 0 with pyhf

Tags: pyhf

I am trying to obtain the upper limit for `n_observed==0` and `n_background==0` events with +pyhf*, in this case I expect to obtain 2.3 (Table 39.3 [pdg-statistics](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2019/reviews/rpp2018-rev-statistics.pdf) PDF)

I tried to create the workspace with 1 bin where I specified the 'background' sample with `'data':[0]`, and `'observations'` with `'data':[0]` but I am struggling in the correct way to obtain this 2.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the Stack Overflow question [Fit convergence failure in pyhf for small signal model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60089405/fit-convergence-failure-in-pyhf-for-small-signal-model) where we cover that models with bins with `0` for all entries are not valid.